# MySQL to get maximum date for each user id and convert them to sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is my MySQL query

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.pname,
       b.skill,
       date_add(a.end_date, interval 1 DAY) AS available_date
FROM
  (SELECT user.id,
          concat(user.first_name, " ", user.last_name) AS name,
          resource_allocated.project_id,
          project.project_name AS pname,
          resource_allocated.end_date
   FROM USER
   RIGHT JOIN resource_allocated ON user.id = resource_allocated.user_id
   RIGHT JOIN project ON resource_allocated.project_id = project.id
   WHERE resource_allocated.is_active=1) a
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT user.id,
          concat(user.first_name, " ", user.last_name) AS name,
          user_skill.skill_id,
          skill.skill_name AS skill
   FROM USER
   RIGHT JOIN user_skill ON user.id = user_skill.user_id
   RIGHT JOIN skill ON user_skill.skill_id = skill.id) b ON a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.id;
```

This is how the result looks like:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+----------------+
| id |   name   | pname | skill | available_date |
+----+----------+-------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | john doe | hms   | php   | 2019-01-02     |
|  1 | john doe | hms   | react | 2019-01-02     |
|  2 | jane doe | hms   | java  | 2020-01-16     |
|  2 | jane doe | IS    | java  | 2019-06-21     |
|  2 | jane doe | hms   | js    | 2020-01-16     |
|  2 | jane doe | IS    | js    | 2019-06-21     |
+----+----------+-------+-------+----------------+
```

I want mysql query to get the maximum date for each users, something like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+----------------+
| id |   name   | pname | skill | available_date |
+----+----------+-------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | john doe | hms   | php   | 2019-01-02     |
|  1 | john doe | hms   | react | 2019-01-02     |
|  2 | jane doe | hms   | java  | 2020-01-16     |
|  2 | jane doe | IS    | java  | 2020-01-16     |
|  2 | jane doe | hms   | js    | 2020-01-16     |
|  2 | jane doe | IS    | js    | 2020-01-16     |
+----+----------+-------+-------+----------------+
```

If possible, can somebody provide the equivalent sequelize code for the resultant query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the max date (or the last date) in your results then use `max()` function and also use `group by name , pname` at the end

```
max(date_add(a.end_date, interval 1 day)) as available_date
```

And if you want to arrange them by date then write this at the end of the query :

```
group by name, pname order by available_date
```

so the final query will look like  :

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.pname,
       b.skill,
       max(date_add(a.end_date, interval 1 day)) as available_date
FROM
  (SELECT user.id,
          concat(user.first_name, " ", user.last_name) AS name,
          resource_allocated.project_id,
          project.project_name AS pname,
          resource_allocated.end_date
   FROM USER
   RIGHT JOIN resource_allocated ON user.id = resource_allocated.user_id
   RIGHT JOIN project ON resource_allocated.project_id = project.id
   WHERE resource_allocated.is_active=1) a
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT user.id,
          concat(user.first_name, " ", user.last_name) AS name,
          user_skill.skill_id,
          skill.skill_name AS skill
   FROM USER
   RIGHT JOIN user_skill ON user.id = user_skill.user_id
   RIGHT JOIN skill ON user_skill.skill_id = skill.id) b ON (a.id = b.id)
GROUP by name, pname , skill
ORDER by a.id, available_date;
```

Comment: I already tried this method. What it did was consider the entire table and showed the row with the maximum date. It didn't get the max date for each user.

Comment: I edited the answer , according to your requirements . Basically I added group by clause which will solve the issue

Comment: @vishawapandya - Still the same result.

Comment: @Kishan - Modified a the query a bit, run it let me know. This time it might work.

Comment: I tried your query, but still, Karan has two dates.